# req. body. name undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I am work on a simple blog page using: ejs, js, node, express,body-parser .

when I used req.body.name for passing inputs to cmd, like here i want to pass the title:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/compose", (req, res) => {
  res.render("compose", { compose: compose });
});

app.post("/compose", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.title); //input name
});

const port = process.env.PORT;

app.listen(port || 3000, () => {
  console.log("ss");
});
```

I get error in command line pointing out that it's undefined, but when i tried using req.body without specify the name it work and shows the input content in command line like this :

```
{ 'title ': 'day1', 'posts ': 'hello' }
{ 'title ': 'day2', 'posts ': 'hey' }
```

and i need to specify which input i need, here is my inputs in compose.ej page:

```
<form class="row g-3" action="/compose" method="post">
  <label class="form-label"> Title</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="title " type="text" />
  <label class="form-label"> Post</label>
  <textarea class="form-control" name="posts" cols="30" rows="6">
    ...
  </textarea>
</form>;
```

Comment: also in the console, there's one error:   Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Answer (score 1):

It is `title`  not `title` so do `req.body['title ']`
Or correct the form `name='title'` without space at the end.

Comment: I delete it but still nothing change ):

Answer (score 1):

you just need to add this line `app.use(express.json());`  after `app.use(express.static("public"));`
it will parses the incoming requests with JSON